# Unable to fetch Email and profile pic from installed Linkedin app

Tags: ios, swift, linkedin-api

I am trying to fetch Linkedin User's following details like Name, email-id, profilePic, id.

I am able to fetch all the details except email-id and profilePic.

**Fetching details via Linkedin url**

```
{
    firstName = Apple;
    formattedName = "Apple Live";
    id = 7uRZgpgwgO;
    lastName = Live;
    picture_url = "" ;
    email-id = "abc@gmail.com"
}
```

**Fetching details via Linkedin app**

```
{
    firstName = Apple;
    formattedName = "Apple Live";
    id = 7uRZgpgwgO;
    lastName = Live;
}
```

**Linkedin app code**

```
LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().getRequest("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,maiden-name,email-address,picture-url,formattedName)?format=json", success: {
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code solved my issue

To get email address via app:

`[LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION,LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION]`

To get Profile Pic:

`picture-urls::(original)`